# Failed to get device list from HomeGraph: Requested entity was not found

Tags: google-home, test-suite, google-smart-home

I have implemented Smart home actions as per documentation, i have enabled Home graph api, 
i got `agentUserId` from Google Oauth playground, but when i submit `agentUserId` and service account key in test suite its returns an  `Error 404` msg:

```
Failed to get device list from HomeGraph: Requested entity was not found.
```

I am able to operate my devices from google home app, but not able to test with test suite.

I am looking for possible reasons.

Comment: If you're getting a 404, I would check that the agentUserId is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this today, and was confused as nothing was even trying to contact my server. I had been using the test tool successfully beforehand, so I knew my `agentUserId` was correct, that HomeGraph API was enabled and my service account was correct. It turned out that I was not currently linked to my Google Home app on my mobile with the same user at the time I was trying to run the test tool. I had unlinked it, therefore the `agentUserId` was not found on Google's side.

To summarise:

1. On your mobile link to your test Action
2. Make sure this is the same user account which you have the agentUserId from - ideally capture a log of your SYNC output and compare
3. Verify your service account's key in the JSON file you upload is listed in the list of "private_key_id"s in your service account
4. Try the test tool again whilst you are still linked on your mobile

Comment: Being linked to my service in the Google Home app was the issue for me. Thanks!